# What is the fastest way of converting a numpy array to a ctype array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, ctypes, numpy-ndarray

Here is a snippet of code I have to convert a numpy array to c_float ctype array so I can pass it to some functions in C language:

```
arr = my_numpy_array
arr = arr/255.
arr = arr.flatten()
new_arr = (c_float*len(arr))()
new_arr[:] = arr
```

but since the last line is actually a for loop and we all know how notorious python is when it comes to for loops for a medium size image array it takes about 0.2 seconds!! so this one line is right now the bottle neck of my whole pipeline. I want to know if there is any faster way of doing it.

## Update

Please note **"to pass to a function in C"** in the question. To be more specific I want to put a numpy array in `IMAGE` data structure and pass it to `rgbgr_image`  function. You can find both [here](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/f6d861736038da22c9eb0739dca84003c5a5e275/python/darknet.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to do it in this weird way using numpy:

```
arr = my_numpu_array
arr = arr/255.
arr = arr.flatten()
arr_float32 = np.copy(arr).astype(np.float32)
new_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(arr_float32)
```

In my case it works 10 times faster.

[Edit]: I don't know why it doesn't work without `np.copy` or with `reshape(-1)`. So it would be awesome if anyone can explain.

Comment: Beware, `flatten` only changes the view on the array and `astype` does a copy itself. So you could leave those two steps out: `arr_float32 = my_numpy_array.astype(np.float32) / 255`.

Comment: @Jeronimo Check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten). `flatten` also makes a copy.

Comment: @tel Even better then.

Comment: I know and I tried... it's all fine as far as you are in python.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's answer makes 4 copies of the `my_numpu_array`, at least 3 of which should be unnecessary. Here's a version that avoids them:

```
# random array for demonstration
my_numpy_array = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10, 10))

# copy my_numpy_array to a float32 array
arr = my_numpy_array.astype(np.float32)

# divide in place
arr /= 255

# reshape should return a view, not a copy, unlike flatten
ctypes_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(arr.reshape(-1))
```

In some circumstances, [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) will return a copy, but since `arr` is guaranteed to own it's own data, it should return a view here.

Comment: I tried these, that's why I think my answer is "weird". They look the same in python: shape and type. but  passing it to a function written in C it crashes. I have to have that ```np.copy``` I think it has something to do with the pointer I pass.. Also it doesn't work with ```reshape```.

Comment: @EhsanFathi: I think you might be running into [numpy#12566](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/12566), which will be fixed in 1.16